# Catching a SQL Server double-message error in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

There are several statements in SQL Server that throw more than one error. An example is the select statement with incomplete column level permissions. Assuming you have a setup like this

```
CREATE USER TestUser1 WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE TABLE dbo.tst(id INT, c1 INT, c2 INT);
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.tst(id) TO TestUser1;
```

If you now, as TestUser1, execute a simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.tst;` in SQL Server Management Studio, two messages are returned:

```
Msg 230, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The SELECT permission was denied on the column 'c1' of the object 'tst', database 'tempdb', schema 'dbo'.
Msg 230, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The SELECT permission was denied on the column 'c2' of the object 'tst', database 'tempdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

However, if I execute something like the following I always only get the first error:

```
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true;"))
        {
            try
            {
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand {CommandText = cmd.ToString(), Connection = conn};
                conn.Open();
                var r = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(e.Message+"\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

SQL Server Management Studio displays both errors, so there seems to be a method to capture both messages.

Just, what is that method?

Answer (score 1):

There is an **Errors** property collection attached to the SqlException object.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index #" + i + "\n" +
            "Error: " + e.Errors[i].ToString() + "\n");
    }
```

Walking through this collection will give you all of the errors...

Comment: That is correct if you call ExecuteNonQuery() but not with ExecuteReader()